# Handle videoview on Orientation Change android

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-videoview

I am working on a videoplayer app. But when I change the orientation the video starts from  beginning. I looked at some solutions but most of them said to use

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

But it dint help.
Any solutions?
Thanks
Code is as below:

```
public class Video2 extends ActionBarActivity {
   final VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.bdayvideoview);
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("current position",view.getCurrentPosition() );
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
       int currentPos =  savedInstanceState.getInt("current position");
        view.seekTo(currentPos);
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.birthdayvideo);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    mediaController.setAnchorView(view);
    view.setMediaController(mediaController);

    view.start();

}
```

}

Comment: You have to use onSavedInstanceState and onViewStateRestored to persist the state on rotation

Comment: @AndroidLearner I have done that too but it din't help. I have updated the code in question.

Comment: @Maulik update your question with code so that I can help you

Comment: @AndroidLearner See the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onSaveInstanceState** in your Activity to save the current time of the movie and restore the video on this same minute with **onRestoreInstanceState**.

Comment: do you have anything on method "onResume"? Where do you start the video, where do you call view.start()?

Comment: No! And I got an error.
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Put the view initialisation inside onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the check for savedInstanceState into your onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.birthdayvideo);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2;
    view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    mediaController.setAnchorView(view);
    view.setMediaController(mediaController);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        int currentPos =  savedInstanceState.getInt("current position");
        view.seekTo(currentPos);
    }

    view.start();

}
```